# Hide html form enlarge element

Tags: html, css

I do not understand how I can hide a form in html without enlarging the other element. This is a dropdown menu with a html form hide:

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">                                       Language <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>                                                  </a>                                                   
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background:#a2a2a2">
    <li>
        <form id="form-ItemIDLangID" action="ItemView.php" method="post">
            <a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById('form-ItemIDLangID').submit();">English</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemPOST" value='itemID'>
            <input type="hidden" name="langPOST" value='langID'>
       </form>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

without the form:

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">                                       Language <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>                                                    </a>                                                 
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background:#a2a2a2">
    <li>
        <a href="#">English</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

this is the result:

[image]

I can't understand how I can use the form and not have that enlarged effect in the first image, I want it to look like the second image, how I can solve it?

Comment: have you got a link to the website so we can see the live version

Comment: Is on your css stylesheet some class like this `form >`?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle or provide a link to your site, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have invalid HTML. An LI can only be the sibling of other LIs. [Update: I wasn't seeing the UL that was WAY offscreen. My mistake.]

Then, you probably have styles on your form that cause the gray space in your image--something like `form {margin-bottom: 15px;}`. Without your CSS or a demo it's impossible to say.

Comment: Where is the LI that isn't a sibling of the others?  I only see them as children under the UL so I must be missing it.

Comment: In each of your snippets you have anchors as siblings of LIs.

Comment: I think you are just missing the UL tag that is way way on the right side of the code.  You have to scroll right.  Ill go ahead and edit his answer to space it out better.

Comment: You're right. Clayton, I was. Proper formatting would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem.  I went ahead and took care of it so it should be better for everyone.